# Python-MSSQL (pymssql) Set a field Identity Column

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, pymssql, identity-column

I have been trying to set the ObjectID as Identity column using python on SQL. The below SQL statment works on Management Studio (SSMS) and sets the ObjectID as Identity column. The code works, but when checking the table on SSMS, I don't see ObjectID as Identity column.

The following ways work on python but do not change the identity column on SSMS.

1. Adding `conn.commit()` after each execution.
2. Running the .sql file with python file reader.

Shown in the image, the Identity column is still empty after code execution in python.

[image]

The code was generated by SSMS, and my purpose is to SET ObjectID field Identity column. Maybe there is a better way.

Here is the code:

```
newTableName = "A_Test_DashAutomation"
try:
    cursor.execute("""
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    SET ARITHABORT ON
    SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
    SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
    COMMIT
    BEGIN TRANSACTION """)

    cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_""" + newTableName + """
        (
        SubProjectTempId bigint NULL,
        CIPNumber varchar(16) NOT NULL,
        Label nvarchar(50) NULL,
        Date_Started datetime2(7) NULL,
        Date_Completed datetime2(7) NULL,
        Status nvarchar(25) NULL,
        Shape geography NULL,
        Type varchar(2) NOT NULL,
        ProjectCode varchar(16) NULL,
        ActiveFlag int NULL,
        Category varchar(32) NULL,
        ProjectDescription varchar(64) NULL,
        UserDefined varchar(1024) NULL,
        InactiveReasonDate datetime NULL,
        FYTDBudget money NULL,
        LTDBudget money NULL,
        PeriodExpenses money NULL,
        FYTDExpenses money NULL,
        LTDExpenses money NULL,
        LTDEncumbrances money NULL,
        LTDBalance money NULL,
        FiscalYear int NULL,
        ToPeriod int NULL,
        _LastImported datetime NOT NULL,
        OBJECTID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
        GDB_GEOMATTR_DATA varbinary(MAX) NULL
        )  ON [PRIMARY]
         TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
    """)

    cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_" + newTableName + " SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)")

    cursor.execute("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_" + newTableName + " ON")

    cursor.execute("""
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.""" + newTableName + """)
         EXEC('INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_""" + newTableName + """ (SubProjectTempId, CIPNumber, Label, Date_Started, Date_Completed, Status, Shape, Type, ProjectCode, ActiveFlag, Category, ProjectDescription, UserDefined, InactiveReasonDate, FYTDBudget, LTDBudget, PeriodExpenses, FYTDExpenses, LTDExpenses, LTDEncumbrances, LTDBalance, FiscalYear, ToPeriod, _LastImported, OBJECTID, GDB_GEOMATTR_DATA)
            SELECT SubProjectTempId, CIPNumber, Label, Date_Started, Date_Completed, Status, Shape, Type, ProjectCode, ActiveFlag, Category, ProjectDescription, UserDefined, InactiveReasonDate, FYTDBudget, LTDBudget, PeriodExpenses, FYTDExpenses, LTDExpenses, LTDEncumbrances, LTDBalance, FiscalYear, ToPeriod, _LastImported, OBJECTID, GDB_GEOMATTR_DATA FROM dbo.""" + newTableName + """ WITH (HOLDLOCK TABLOCKX)')
    """)

    cursor.execute("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tmp_" + newTableName + " OFF")

    cursor.execute("DROP TABLE dbo." + newTableName)

    cursor.execute("EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Tmp_" + newTableName + "', N'" + newTableName + "', 'OBJECT'")

    cursor.execute("""
    ALTER TABLE dbo.""" + newTableName + """ ADD CONSTRAINT
        R1143_pk PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
        OBJECTID
        ) WITH( PAD_INDEX = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 75, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

    """)

    cursor.execute("""
    CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SIndx ON dbo.""" + newTableName + """(Shape) USING GEOGRAPHY_AUTO_GRID
         WITH( CELLS_PER_OBJECT  = 16, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
    """)

    cursor.execute("""
    ALTER TABLE dbo.""" + newTableName + """ ADD CONSTRAINT
        g1084_ck CHECK (([Shape].[STSrid]=(4326)))
    """)

    cursor.execute("COMMIT")

    conn.commit()
    print("Object ID is set to Identify column.")

except pymssql.DatabaseError, err:
    print(str(err))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Your code works fine for me, both with pymssql (v2.1.3) and pyodbc (v4.0.23). You will need to create a [mcve] that will reproduce your specific issue and then [edit] your question with the details.

Comment: Hopefully, this looks better

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The STSrid changes everytime you create a new table, so taking this portion out of the SQL code helped. However, I am not sure if the spatial index remained the same.

Cheers

```
cursor.execute("""
ALTER TABLE dbo.""" + newTableName + """ ADD CONSTRAINT
    g1084_ck CHECK (([Shape].[STSrid]=(4326))) """)
```